# Swift & StompClientLib : stompClient(_) function did not get call

Tags: ios, swift, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

Our team is using this `StompClientLib` in Swift to work with `WebSocket`. The document isn't that well explanatory. And there is one function that I don't quite understand. That function is called `stompClient()`. I notice that it didn't get called, so we cannot check our websocket data.

```
func stompClient(client: StompClientLib!, didReceiveMessageWithJSONBody jsonBody: AnyObject?, akaStringBody stringBody: String?, withHeader header: [String : String]?, withDestination destination: String) {
    print("Value  : \(destination), \(String(describing: jsonBody)) & \(stringBody ?? "nil")")
}
```

Coming from a frontend/mobile app development background, I don't quite know what websocket or backend overall really is and how it really works. Could anyone please answer my question below?

1 - What is the function `stompClient` for?

2 - If the function didn't get called when it is supposed to, what could be the possible problem?

`StompClientLib` : https://github.com/WrathChaos/StompClientLib

FYI, we use `SpringBoot` as our backend.

I'm looking forward to hearing your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own questions.

1 - `stompClient` will keep listening to the WebSocket and will be running only when there is any change/trigger from the WebSocket.

2 - After debugging, it turned out the WebSocket on the backend wasn't configured properly. Thus, it didn't trigger any data to the Frontend.